Add comma to price using Babel
We are using Fresh Relevance (a site personalization and AB testing tool) to add product recommendation carousels to our website. For each product card we are showing the price, and we need it to be in this format: $1,111. It currently looks like this: $1111. We want to add in the comma.
I've been editing the template for the carousel (I'm familiar with html, css, jquery), but I can't figure out what language the price part of the template is in:
<div class="{{safeid}}__product-price">
                                    <a href="{{ mergeField(fields.redirectURL, { product: product })|set_ga_tracking(
                                        utm_campaign=mergeField(fields.utmCampaign, {}),
                                        utm_medium=mergeField(fields.utmMedium, {}),
                                        utm_source=mergeField(fields.utmSource, {})) }}" target="_blank">
                                        {{ product.uv|format_currency(product.curr,0) }}
                                    </a>
                                </div>

It's the 6th line that I'm trying to edit. I think it is using Babel and I found some documentation online for the 'format_currency': https://babel.pocoo.org/en/latest/api/numbers.html#babel.numbers.format_currency
I've tried numerous things, and I end up breaking the template every time. I need to keep the
(product.curr,0)

part because we need to remove the decimal part of the price.
I've reached out to Fresh Relevance support (their dev turn-around time is a bit long), and I am hoping someone here can help me out.
